# How can I store input field value within a variable which is inside the td tag in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I append a html table using ajax. Here, I show two value and create one input field. But now i want to take this input field value within a variable and want to show by alert tag. This input field under td tag and i also set a Id in the input field. In a short word, I just take the input value from appending td and store in lval.Code is given below:

table html code:

```
<div class="row">
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tag Location</th>
                    <th>Tag Description</th>
                    <th>Log Value</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tableBody"></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Jquery and Ajax Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myTable").hide();
        var logArray = new Array();
        var lval=0;
        $("#catId").change(function () {
            var catId = $("#catId").val();
            $("#myTable").show();
            var json = { catId: catId };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/SaveLogMaster/GetTagMasterByCatId',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(json),
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                       $("#tableBody").append('<tr><td>' + value.TagLocation + '</td><td>' + value.TagDescription + '</td><td><input type="text" id="lValue" name="LogValue" /></td></tr>');                   

                 lval= $("lValue").val(); // not works.. what i use here
                       alert(lval);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
     });
```

controller code:

```
        public JsonResult GetTagMasterByCatId(int catId)
    {
        return Json(aSaveLogMasterManager.GetTagMasterData(catId));
    }
```

Comment: What is your expected behavior for this jQuery selector `$("lValue")` ? If `lValue` is an `Id`, It should be `$("#lValue")`. But your current code is trying to add same `Id` value to more than one element (inside the loop). That is invalid.

Comment: Also, your input does not have a value attribute at all! What value are you trying to get then ???

Comment: <td><input type="text" id="lValue" name="LogValue" /></td> ... i just want to take this  input field value and store into a variable.. I did it ("#lvalue").but not works. If i want to generate new id for each loop..how can i do that ?

Comment: Like i mentioned in my previous comment, your input does not have a `value` attribute at all. What are you trying to get  ?

Comment: what is value attribute ? this is a text filed. i want to take it from user